# how to move to specific section in panorama?

Tags: windows-phone

In windows phone app ?I am using Panorama control having 3 sections like sports videos and photos.
My app contains one "other" page where names of the pages are present.
Problem: when I click on video page button it should navigate to video section of panorama control
So how to visit a specific section?

Comment: do you need to select any specific item in the panorama?

Comment: no I want user should move to specific section of panorama.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a global static variable in App.xaml.cs like this

public static int SelectedIndexPanorama;

now in "Other" Page assign the value to this variable on specific navigation

```
case "sports":
              App.SelectedIndexPanorama=0;
              NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/sports.xaml? ", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); 
              break; 

case "video":
             App.SelectedIndexPanorama=1;
             NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/video.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); 
             break;
```

And, on panorama page OnNavigatedToEvent, write the code to set the selectedItem

```
myPanorama.SetValue(Panorama.SelectedItemProperty, myPanorama.Items[App.SelectedIndexPanorama]);
```

Comment: how App.SelectedIndexPanorama=0; used in navigation service?

Comment: no need to use it inside navigationservice just set it above navigationservice.Navigate line.

Comment: still it is not giving proper output.It is navigating to 1 st section only.How to define index for section?

Comment: case "sports":
                    
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/sports.xaml?  ", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    break;

                case "video":
                         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/video.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                               break;

Comment: Like this way I am using cases.So how to navigate to particular section in panorama?